# Four quadrant plot, 4 different variables in R

Tags: r, plot, coordinates

I am trying to create a coordinate plot in R that shows all four quadrants. What I need is different from anything I've seen in typical data visualizations. I have attached a picture example of what I need to achieve.

You'll notice that there are no negative values because each quadrant is representing different variable combinations with scores ranging from 0 to 25.

I have not found an example of what I need to do, so I don't have 'tried and failed' code, but I have a sample data set in wide and long format depending on what the solution would require. I looked at plots in ggplot2, but I could only plot using 2 variables. I am not sure how to represent all 4 variables using something like geom_point.

I only want to show the coordinates for one person at a time, so I do not want everyone's score from the dataset to be plotted at once.

Any ideas on how to approach this is greatly appreciated!

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(
    name = c("Donald", "Minnie", "Pluto"),
    varA = c(3, 6, 15),
    varB = c(4, 17, 6),
    varC = c(26, 21, 13),
    varD = c(10, 19, 19)
    )

library(reshape2)
dflong <- melt(df, id.vars='name', measure.vars=c("varA", "varB", "varC", "varD"))
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "I only want to show the coordinates for one person at a time, so I do not want everyone's score from the dataset to be plotted at once."? Would'nt that look like the picture you provided? It is unclear to me what your desired solution looks like

Comment: Yes, it would look exactly like the picture, but I drew the pic in Word, not R, just as a sample of what I need R to produce. I have a class of about 45 students and I need to produce individual graphs for each student showing only that student's scores. I typically code figures in R, then copy/paste the graphic into another file for the student's report.

Comment: I don't think this is natively possible with ggplot2. There might be a package somewhere that could achieve this but I'd rather suggest to either squeeze your data that it produces the desired output, create multiple graphs and combine them, or use a more flexible/customizable visualization program than ggplot2

Comment: I was not optimistic when I posted this question. I'm looking at some other options that might be satisfactory. Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this with tidyr, dplyr and ggplot2:

The plot may need some jigging about to make it look like you want.

If you only want one plot at a time just filter the data frame in the call to ggplot.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  name = c("Donald", "Minnie", "Pluto"),
  varA = c(3, 6, 15),
  varB = c(4, 17, 6),
  varC = c(26, 21, 13),
  varD = c(10, 19, 19)
)

df1 <- 
  df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-name, names_to = "var", names_prefix = "var", values_to = "val") %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(quad = paste(var, lead(var, default = "A"), sep = "-"),
         x = case_when(var == "A" ~ lead(val),
                       var == "B" ~ val,
                       var == "C" ~ -lead(val),
                       var == "D" ~ -val),
         y = case_when(var == "A" ~ val,
                       var == "B" ~ -lead(val),
                       var == "C" ~ -val,
                       var == "D" ~ lag(val, n = 3)))
# helper value
val_max <- round(max(df1$val), -1)

# axis data
df_ax <- data.frame(ax = rep(c("x", "y"), each = 2),
                    x = c(-val_max, val_max, 0, 0),
                    y = c(0, 0, -val_max, val_max)) 
#labels for variables
labs <- data.frame(label = LETTERS[1:4],
                   val = val_max,
                   x = c( 0, val_max, 0, -val_max),
                   y = c( val_max, 0, -val_max, 0))

ggplot(df1, aes(x, y))+
  geom_point(size = 3)+
  facet_wrap(~name)+
  geom_line(data = df_ax, aes(x, y, group = ax))+
  geom_text(data = labs, aes(x, y, label = label),
            nudge_x = c(0, 2, 0, -2),
            nudge_y = c(2, 0, -2, 0),
            size = 4)+
  geom_text(data = labs, aes(x, y, label = val),
            nudge_x = c( -2, -2, -2, 2),
            nudge_y = c( -2, -2, 2, -2),
            size = 3)+
  geom_text(aes(x = 2, y = 2, label = 0), size = 3, check_overlap = TRUE)+
  coord_fixed(xlim = c(-val_max - 2, val_max + 2),
              ylim = c(-val_max -2 , val_max + 2))+
  labs(x = NULL,
       y = NULL)+
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much.